# How to get value by instance of type Result<Credentials>?

Tags: swift, generics

In my application using `auth0` for login and after successful login i am getting an object in callback with data type `Result<Credentials>` Now I need values in `Credentials` how can I get that. Object gives no tele sense. function name is `func start(_ callback: @escaping (Result<Credentials>) -> Void)`  my code is

```
wa.start { (result) in
            print(result)
            let acb = result
        }
```

> where
>   `Result` object have

```
public enum Result<T> {
    case success(result: T)
    case failure(error: Error)
}
```

> and `Credentials` Object have

```
@objc public let accessToken: String?
@objc public let tokenType: String?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Result` is an `enum`, so you can `switch` on an instance of it…

```
wa.start { result in
    switch result {
    case let .success(credentials):
        // Handle your credentials here…
    case let .failure(error):
        // Present an error
    }
}
```